# why it returns empty value but of boolean type when no match is found

Tags: php, arrays, search, multidimensional-array

I am using the following code to search an element inside a multi dimensional array.When a match is found it returns the index.But when no match is found it returns a empty value.Not 0 or 1.But if i print out the type , it says boolean.What does that boolean mean if it returns empty.Does it mean that it will be equal to empty string ?

```
$arr =Array
(
    0 => Array
        (
            'uid' => '100',
            'name' => 'Sandra Shush'
        ),

    1 => Array
        (
            'uid' => '5465',
            'name' => 'Stefanie Mcmohn'      
        ),

    2 => Array
        (
            'uid' => '40489',
            'name' => 'Michael'   
        )
);

$match = array_search('546',array_column($arr, 'uid'));

echo gettype($match);
```

Comment: "Returns the key for needle if it is found in the array, FALSE otherwise." So it's boolean when returned FALSE

Comment: You stumble about how `FALSE` is displayed. `FALSE` is _not_ equal to `0`, though often visualized as such. You may convert it to things in an implicit manner. A conversion of `FALSE` to a string delivers the empty string indeed. But that does not mean that the search function returns an empty string. It returns `FALSE`.

Comment: it simply says when its `FALSE`, it means not found, you used `gettype(FALSE)`, thus the boolean echoed

Comment: array_search() Searches the array for a given value and returns the first corresponding key if successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`array_search()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) returns `FALSE` when it cannot find the needle in the haystack.

The comparison is done using `==`. This means, the values are converted to the same type, if needed. But their values must be the same after conversion. It doesn't match substrings.

`echo(FALSE);` doesn't print anything. The type of `FALSE` is [`boolean`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php), indeed. And `FALSE` is [`==`](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php) with the empty string (`''`), zero (`0`), the string that contain the number zero (`'0'`) [and other empty values](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at array_search method description http://php.net/manual/ro/function.array-search.php it says: Returns the key for needle if it is found in the array, FALSE otherwise. There is your answer.

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.

When converting to boolean, the following values are considered FALSE:

```
the boolean FALSE itself
the integer 0 (zero)
the float 0.0 (zero)
the empty string, and the string "0"
an array with zero elements
the special type NULL (including unset variables)
SimpleXML objects created from empty tags
```

Every other value is considered TRUE (including any resource and NAN).

Answer (score 2):

`array_search()` function returns the key for needle if it is found in the array, FALSE otherwise. So when you are using `gettype()` on the return value, then it will return the type of `FALSE` i.e. `BOOLEAN` for unsuccessful search, otherwise `INT` index value.

Answer (score 2):

your code is working , when array_search not found then return `false` and if  gettype($match); then show boolean and if found then return index so in this case return `integer`

this is code which return

```
<?php
$arr =Array
(
    0 => Array
        (
            'uid' => '100',
            'name' => 'Sandra Shush'
        ),

    1 => Array
        (
            'uid' => '5465',
            'name' => 'Stefanie Mcmohn'      
        ),

    2 => Array
        (
            'uid' => '40489',
            'name' => 'Michael'   
        )
);

$match = array_search('5465',array_column($arr, 'uid'));

echo gettype($match);
```

and output is: `integer`

this is normal example

```
<?php
$array = array(0 => 'blue', 1 => 'red', 2 => 'green', 3 => 'red');

$key = array_search('green', $array); // $key = 2;
$key = array_search('red', $array);   // $key = 1;
?>
```

for more information

http://php.net/manual/ro/function.array-search.php